# NodeJs - Wait for a promise resolution from an asyncronous method.

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bluebird

I've written a validation library that I want to be able to call synchronously and asynchronously in Node. I've tried to use promises with async/co but I 
can't get anywhere. Does anyone have a good suggestion for how to be able to make this code sync? I'm trying to call this from a validation factory and the lookup returned is reaching out async to a data base.

```
var lookupFactory = require('../lookup/lookupFactory');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var async = require('async');

exports.validate = function (required, field, errors) {
    if (required && field.value == null) {
        errors.push('Field is required');
       return;
   }

    var lookupType = field.validation.lookupType;
    var s = lookupFactory.lookup(lookupType);
    s.validate('12', function (err, data) {
        if (data.length != 1) {
            errors.push('Field value is not valid');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you saying that `s.validate` is asynchronous? If yes, then you *cannot* call your function synchronously; if no, then there's not point in "making" your function asynchronous and using promises or async.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.validate = function (required, field) {
  var lookupType = field.validation.lookupType;
  var s = lookupFactory.lookup(lookupType);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (required && field.value == null) {
      return reject('Field is required');
    }

    s.validate('12', function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
        return reject(err);
      } else if (data.length != 1) {
        return reject('Field value is not valid');
      }

      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Example usage:

```
validate(true, 'name')
  .then(function(data) { console.log('Validation succeeded:', data); },
        function(reason) { console.log('Validation failed:', reason); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like promisses.

```
exports.validate = function (required, field, errors) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill) {
        if (required && field.value == null) {
            errors.push('Field is required');
            return;
        }

        var lookupType = field.validation.lookupType;
        var s = lookupFactory.lookup(lookupType);
        s.validate('12', function (err, data) {
            if (data.length != 1) {
                errors.push('Field value is not valid');
            }
            fulfill(null /*Argument passed to the other function*/); //Is it here the code end?
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this really changed the way I approached the code. Sadly though promises just lead me down rewriting a bunch of code.